# Session in Laravel does not save variable

Tags: php, laravel, session, controller, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel to make an e-commerce site, and I want anybody to add items to the cart, not just auth users, so I use the session to generate the `cart_id` variable.

I made new middleware to check whether the session has `cart_id`. If not, it has generated a new uniquid.

```
class CartId{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Session::has('cart_id')) {
            $cart_id = uniqid();
            Session::put(['cart_id'=>$cart_id]);
            Session::save();
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But when I try to make `dd(session()->get('cart_id'))`, I get a new id every refresh. Why? I'm using this package: darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart. I'd tried to make `php artisan optimize:clear` and nothing worked.

Comment: i replicated the code and it works for me, maybe check the SESSION_LIFETIME variable in the .env file

Comment: what routes are you assigning this middleware to? do all these routes have the 'web' group of middleware assigned?

Comment: Session::put(['cart_id'=>$cart_id]); $request->session('cart_id')->save();

Comment: thnx all ,, my code work fine in other project so i made a new laravel project and it work good

Answer (score 0):

thnx all ,, my code work fine in other project so i made a new laravel project and it work good

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).